# Task Scheduler "stop task if it runs longer than" doesn't work

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I try to use "stop task if it runs longer than" in Windows 10 Task Scheduler both inside the task trigger and inside the Settings tab, but it actually doesn't stop the program in the time was set, and the status remains running. (It doesn't change if refresh the Scheduler) What did I set wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SU. I'd suggest providing a bit more context for this question. Please see the [guidelines for questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775588/edit) your question to update it accordingly. As a new user it's a good idea to check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and Asking and Answering -sections in the Help Center to learn how the site works. Also reviewing some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) is helpful.